# stack "Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain" when trying to build 'node-gyp configure'

Tags: node.js, npm, protractor, node-gyp, mssql-jdbc

I got below error when trying to build the microsoft driver for nodejs for sql server

> gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
>
> gyp info using node-gyp@3.2.1
>
> gyp info using node@5.3.0 | win32 | x64
>
> gyp http GET
>   https://nodejs.org/download/release/v5.3.0/node-v5.3.0-headers.tar.gz
>
> gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
>
> gyp ERR! configure error
>
> gyp ERR! stack **Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain**
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket. (_tls_wrap.js:1057:38)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
>
> gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._fini`enter code here`shInit
>
> gyp ERR! not ok "

i tried with below workaround but it dint work

```
1) upgrade your version of npm

npm install npm -g --ca=null

- or -

2) tell your current version of npm to use known registrars  

npm config set ca=""
```

Can anyone guide me how to resolve this certificate issue

Comment: Is there an antivirus that is blocking npm access? What version of npm are you using currently? Thanks

Comment: npm version is 3.5.2 , yes there is a McAfee antivirus system is corporate network ,Thanks Dilip

Comment: Can you try disabling the antivirus and perform the installation? HTTPS protection can often block npm from building the packages. Thanks

Comment: Since my system is in corporate network i will not be able to do it , is there any other way to bypass it , Thanks Dilip

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately node-gyp doesn't utilize npm's certificate settings.

If you are calling node-gyp, you can updated to the latest node-gyp then utilize a new `--cafile` parameter to supposedly provide a valid ca certificate.

If you are using npm to install a package that builds itself with node-gyp, your only recourse is a hack to set `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` environment variable beforehand, to have it ignore CA certificate issues.

See discussion on github here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/695

Comment: changes goes into node environment, not into system environment.
npm config set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Comment: @pixelquadrat Am pretty sure that isn't the case. Using the `npm config` command made no difference for me, whereas using the environment variable got past the issue (...and onto another one but that's a different story!)

Comment: Check this link maybe this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722457/how-to-prevent-node-gyp-from-downloading-node-headers-tar-gz-and-node-lib-from-i

Answer (score 3):

For me gyp rebuild could not find binding.gyp and it was trying to download it.
Try running:

`sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm binding`

Answer (score 3):

Came across the same problem when `node-gyp` starts compiling `node.js` addons source. And as **@mujimu** suggested, fixed it setting a shell variable `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` value to `0` before executing `npm install`, as follows:

```
$ set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
$ npm install
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your certificate file to be used when doing HTTPS requests using the following command:

```
npm config set cafile /path/to/your/cert.pem --global
```

Comment: doesn't work with node-gyp

Comment: @Rexave sorry my friend! O solved the mentioned issue on 2019. The node-gyp error appeared to me when I wasn't configured Python 3 and the visual C++ SDK on my windows.

Answer (score 2):

Used `npm config set strict-ssl false` and that fixed the issue.

Comment: NOPE same error, Turned OFF VPN.  Boom! it worked.

Comment: Please do NOT do this. Man in the middle attacks are real.

Answer (score 1):

3 steps to solve this if this is related to a corporate proxy:

1. Retrieve public cert and convert them to .pem format. The file looks like this. `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTBLABLA...MORECHARSHERE -----END CERTIFICATE-----\n------BEGIN CERTIFICATE ... etc` depends on your company
2. Store them somewhere on your pc. I store them in my repo
3. In a terminal execute
   `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/home/<yourUser>/git/myproject/certs/myBundle.pem npm i --quiet`

For Windows you've got to change that to: `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=C:\Users\<yourUser>\git\myproject\certs\myBundle.pem npm i --quiet`

Comment: How to retrieve the public cert and convert them to .pem format?

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that worked for me was to use the `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` environment variable to pass in the self-signed certificate.  `node-gyp` doesn't look at the config files for `npm` nor at any of `npm`s environment variables.  But using the NODE env var does seem to get through.

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling Angular/cli first and installing node-gyp and then try reinstalling Angular cli

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g node-gyp
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

It works perfectly

Comment: NOPE same error, Turned OFF VPN.  Boom! it worked.