# How to prevent node-gyp from downloading node-headers.tar.gz and node.lib from internet?

Tags: node.js, npm, node-gyp

node-gyp downloads following files from the Internet during installation and building of the native modules like iconv, ref, ffi, etc:
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.10.0/node-v6.10.0-headers.tar.gz
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.10.0/win-x86/node.lib
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.10.0/win-x64/node.lib
https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.10.0/SHASUMS256.txt

How to make node-gyp to use these files from local folders, not from the Internet?

I've found the following solution:
1. Download https://nodejs.org/download/release/v6.10.0/node-v6.10.0-headers.tar.gz
2. Unpack it to some local folder.
3. Create folder Release in this local folder.
4. Download file https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.0/win-x64/node.lib into the folder Release.
5. Set property nodedir in .npmrc which will point to the folder with unpacked headers:
nodedir=D:\tools\node_src\node-v6.10.0-headers

Now npm installs packages and node-gyp builds native packages without downloading node headers and libs from the Internet.
Is it a correct approach?

I cannot find in the documentation that I should download node.lib and put it to the Release directory.
I decided to do it after analyzing the traces of node-gyp and code of node-gyp.
Is it possible to setup the location of node.lib using some npm_config_xxx property?

Comment: This post just saved me. Thankyou.

Comment: Just don't forget about this when you decide to update your node version. Spent half an hour banging my head against the table cause `>> npm rebuild node-sass` didn't work : D

Answer (score 12):

For those running on Windows where `--tarball` is useless because node-gyp subsequently wants to download the node.lib file...

Here was my solution, hope to help anyone else stuck behind corporate barriers. I'm using v16.2.0 as an example, so swap with your appropriate node version.

Create a folder you're happy to house 16.2.0 data and point to it with the terminal command. I chose `%USERPROFILE%\.node-gyp\16.2.0`. Doesn't have to be in `.node-gyp`.

Create two subfolders within that folder: `Release` and `src`.

Download: https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.2.0/win-x64/node.lib and https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.2.0/node-v16.2.0-headers.tar.gz

Place `node.lib` in the `Release` subfolder.

Open the headers.tar.gz file. I used 7zip. Once inside the tar, navigate to include/node.

Extract the two `.gypi` files into your base folder.

Extract everything else into the `src` subfolder.

Run using `--nodedir=%USERPROFILE%\.node-gyp\16.2.0` (or your equivalent folder if you differed from me)

Comment: Thanks very much for this - my work laptop uses a zScaler cloud proxy service for "security", which replaces SSL certificates. Although I've relaxed SSL checking for npm, gyp was not playing nicely. This workaround has solved the issue, thanks.

Comment: I think maybe 75% of all the problems encoutered in our team are linked to our corporation using zScaler, what a drag.

Comment: Run what using the --nodedir ?  Is this used with npm command?  I didn't see anything to indicate it changed anything, maybe beecause I need other flags as well, or ... something

Comment: All of the above plus check if your node.lib is 32 or 64 bit and use the correct one. Also if you are using node 18.19.0 - folder path to unzip everything else mentioned above will be "YOUR FOLDER PATH"+\include\node. My path was C:\temp\include\node and I added a npmrc variable nodedir = C:\temp, then just did npm install

Answer (score 9):

Below works for me:

```sh
# download for private repo, probably you're behind firewall
curl -k -o node-v8.9.4-headers.tar.gz -L https://nexus.com/repository/binaries/node/v8.9.4/node-v8.9.4-headers.tar.gz

# capture the absolute path
TARBALL_PATH=$(pwd)

# configure tarball in npm config
npm config set tarball ${TARBALL_PATH}/node-v8.9.4-headers.tar.gz

# The below command should pass without gyp error
npm install
```

Comment: Fantastic thank you!  Locally, I get around this by installing node-gyp globally then running `node-gyp rebuild --dist-url=https://url/to/your/binaries/"` ... This will install the necessary headers on your machine.  Then you can run things normally.

HOWEVER, this doesn't work in a CI build so your solution is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way to reverse the effects of this command? I ran this, and now Yarn crashes because it can't find the file. Re-running with a more recent version of Node hasn't helped at all.

Comment: npm config saves its configurations either in user or global npmrc file (not recommended to edit the file manually). You can perform CRUD operation using `npm config`  command. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-config

Answer (score 4):

As it suggests here, you can use the --tarball option for node-gyp
https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1133

Comment: This doesn't work on windows where the --tarball options don't load the 'node.lib' file, only the headers