# How can I set the node-gyp's paths for config.gypi and common.gypi when running npm install?

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm trying to run npm install after starting to make a PCF Component and ran into the following error:

`npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack FetchError: request to https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.12.1/node-v18.12.1-headers.tar.gz failed, reason: write EPROTO 1C4D0000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\statem\extensions.c:922:`

To get around it, I followed through the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722457/how-to-prevent-node-gyp-from-downloading-node-headers-tar-gz-and-node-lib-from-i) and set, after a lot of unzipping and copy/pasting files to make absolutely certain things get looked at properly, added the following line to my `.npmrc` file: `nodedir=C:\Users\fwilbur001\.node-gyp\18.12.1`. Afterwards, I wound up with a different error:

`npm ERR! gyp WARN read config.gypi ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\fwilbur001\Desktop\dev\project_thing\node_modules\bufferutil\‪C:\Users\fwilbur001\.node-gyp\18.12.1\include\node\config.gypi'`

As you can see, node-gyp is attempting to add the `config.gypi` file's path to, ostensibly, the full path. I ran `npm install --verbose` to get a better look, and what I found is that node-gyp tries to create the `config.gypi` in the module's directory, tries to use Python 3.10, and then fails to locate `common.gypi` because it looks at a bad path (see below):

```
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\fwilbur001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\fwilbur001\\Desktop\\dev\\project_thing\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\fwilbur001\\Desktop\\dev\\project_thing\\node_modules\\bufferutil\\build\\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\fwilbur001\\Desktop\\dev\\project_thing\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\fwilbur001\\Desktop\\dev\\project_thing\\node_modules\\bufferutil\\‪C:\\Users\\fwilbur001\\.node-gyp\\18.12.1\\common.gypi',   
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=‪C:\\Users\\fwilbur001\\.node-gyp\\18.12.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Users\\fwilbur001\\Desktop\\dev\\project_thing\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=‪C:\\\\Users\\\\fwilbur001\\\\.node-gyp\\\\18.12.1\\\\$(Configuration)\\\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\fwilbur001\\Desktop\\dev\\project_thing\\node_modules\\bufferutil',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'C:\\Users\\fwilbur001\\Desktop\\dev\\project_thing\\node_modules\\bufferutil\\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: C:\Users\fwilbur001\Desktop\dev\project_thing\node_modules\bufferutil\\u202aC:\Users\fwilbur001\.node-gyp\18.12.1\common.gypi not found (cwd: C:\Users\fwilbur001\Desktop\dev\project_thing\node_modules\bufferutil) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
```

I'm at a loss. Any advice? Please help.

Comment: For what it's worth: I was ultimately able to resolve this by downgrading npm from version 8.19 to 8.11 and using nvm to go from 18.12.1 to 16.15.1, and editing the .npmrc file to not use the header tarball I had downloaded. Weird, but whatever—at least I can actually start work now.

Comment: The reason Node 16 works is that in Node v17 and higher, OpenSSL has been updated to v3.0.7. SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT is the option that went from enabled by default in OpenSSL 1.1.1 to disabled by default in OpenSSL 3.0