# yarn install fails because node-gyp is looking for dated node version header

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, node-gyp

After upgrading to Node 18.12.0 (on macos Ventura 13.2.1) , I ran into issues with a failed yarn install, with the following error:

[image]

I have attempted:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling Node, npm, and nvm on my machine
- Wiping and recreating npm config
  But nothing works. I can't figure out where this value is set that's making node-gyp look for the headers for the outdated version of node, and manually setting a new tarball hasn't helped. The most likely cause of this was following the second answer on this SO thread([How to prevent node-gyp from downloading node-headers.tar.gz and node.lib from internet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722457/how-to-prevent-node-gyp-from-downloading-node-headers-tar-gz-and-node-lib-from-i)), but not replacing the current Node version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was right in my face the entire time: it never occurred to me to check the Yarn config, which is where the outdated headers were living.

Comment: what do you mean? how did you access and change them: and what did you change them to?